# EWS Mail Search Criteria searching for mails in a particular date and a keyword in subject line

Tags: c#, email, exchangewebservices

I am searching for emails sent today using EWS. I want to pass these date filtered mails to be searched for a keyword in the subject line and in the body, so that I can get the mails which are sent today and have the keywords in the subject. Please help me with the code.

Here is my code:

```
             public static FindItemsResults<Item> MailSearchCriteria(string condition, ExchangeService exchangeService)
             {
        FindItemsResults<Item> searchResult = null;
        string mailsearch = "Demo";
        try
        {


            DateTime date = DateTime.Today;

            //A local variable filter stores the search condition according to the date
            SearchFilter greaterThanfilter = new SearchFilter.IsGreaterThanOrEqualTo(ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived, date);
            SearchFilter lessThanfilter = new SearchFilter.IsLessThan(ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived, date.AddDays(1));
            SearchFilter dateFilter = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And, greaterThanfilter, lessThanfilter);

            //All the mails for the given date is stored in a variable
            searchResult = exchangeService.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, dateFilter, new ItemView(500));

            //Count of all the mails with date filter is stored in an integer variable
            int mailno = searchResult.Count();

            //Runs the loop for the count to be greater than 0
            while (mailno >= 0)
            {
                foreach (Item item in searchResult.Items)
                {

                    string sender= ((EmailMessage)(item)).Sender.Name;

                    if (sender=="sender_name")
                    {
                        //Subject filter criteria
                        //A local variable subjectFilter stores the subject filter pattern passed from the database
                        SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring subjectFilter = new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(ItemSchema.Subject, mailsearch, ContainmentMode.Substring, ComparisonMode.IgnoreCase);

                        //Mail body filter criteria
                        //A local variable bodytFilter stores the body filter pattern passed from the database
                        SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring bodyFilter = new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(ItemSchema.Body, mailsearch, ContainmentMode.Substring, ComparisonMode.IgnoreCase);
                        //Checks the search condition passed from the xml file
                        if (Equals(condition, "OR") && (subjectFilter.Value != string.Empty || bodyFilter.Value != string.Empty))
                        {
                            //Logical OR condition for pattern search in subject or body is stored in a local variable
                            SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection orFilter = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.Or, subjectFilter, bodyFilter);

                            //The mails satisfying the search criteria are stored in a variable
                            searchResult = exchangeService.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, orFilter, new ItemView(10));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //Logical AND condition for pattern search in subject and body is stored in a local variable
                            SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection andFilter = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And, subjectFilter, bodyFilter);

                            //The mails satisfying the search criteria are stored in a variable
                            searchResult = exchangeService.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, andFilter, new ItemView(10));
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //filelog error call
                    }

                }
                //The count is decremented
                mailno--;
            }

            //call fileLog method for success
            //fileLog(1,"successfully searched");
        }

        catch (Exception errormsg)
        {
            //filelog method call
            //fileLog(0,errormsg.Tostring);
        }
        return searchResult;
    }
```

Note: This is my first question. So please feel free to ask any information you need to answer the question.

Comment: Is there a particular problem or something not working, or just dont know how to do it?

Comment: @SimonPrice **i don't know how to do it. the subjectFilter and bodyFilter are filtering all the mails from the inbox.**

Comment: Ok, thats not really what stack is here for in this section, you might want to ask it on another of the stack sites ( there a lot of people who will run you down on here for this)  However.... without an EWS for me to connect to I would struggle to help you fully.  BUT.... two questions, 1 are you able to connect to the mail service you want to connect to? 2. If yes to the first question do you get anthing back from your `searchResult` or do you get any errors?

Comment: @SimonPrice Yes, I am able to connect to the mail server. And the `searchResult` gives me all the mails sent to me today.

Comment: Can you post your complete method please and i'll take a look at this for you

Comment: @SimonPrice I want to pass each item of `searchResult` into `subjectFilter` and `bodyFilter`

Comment: give me your entire method then please

Comment: Im hoping its a simple as `Item.Subject` and `Item.Body`

Comment: @SimonPrice please see the code.. i have added the whole method

Comment: although Ive answered the question below, you secondary searches will only yeild the same results of what you have in searchfilter

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
void Main()
{
DateTime date = DateTime.Today;
var exchangeService = new ExchangeService();

SearchFilter greaterThanfilter = new SearchFilter.IsGreaterThanOrEqualTo(ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived, date);
SearchFilter lessThanfilter = new SearchFilter.IsLessThan(ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived, date.AddDays(1));
SearchFilter dateFilter = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And, greaterThanfilter, lessThanfilter);

//All the mails for the given date is stored in a variable
var searchResult = exchangeService.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, dateFilter, new ItemView(500));

//Count of all the mails with date filter is stored in an integer variable
int mailno = searchResult.Count();

foreach (Item item in searchResult.Items)
{
    string sender = ((EmailMessage)(item)).Sender.Name;

    if (sender == "Sender_name")
    {
        //Subject filter criteria
        //A local variable subjectFilter stores the subject filter pattern passed from the database
        //**I want to pass the 'item' into the subjectFilter and bodyFilter**
                    SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring subjectFilter = new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(ItemSchema.Subject, "Demo", ContainmentMode.Substring, ComparisonMode.IgnoreCase);

        //Mail body filter criteria
        //A local variable bodytFilter stores the body filter pattern passed from the database
        SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring bodyFilter = new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(ItemSchema.Body, "Demo", ContainmentMode.Substring, ComparisonMode.IgnoreCase);

    }
}
```

Comment: I want to search for 'Demo' keyword in the emails.

Comment: This is the same as what I had done.. I want to use the mails stored in `searchResult` to be filtered for subject and body.

Comment: and this should work for you, if its not then this starting to become a question of why isnt my code working which is off topic